# ¿ Como Puedo hacer raspado web de varias paginas donde la url no cambia en R?

Tags: php, javascript, r

Estoy intentando hacer una función que descargue información de esta [pagina](https://listanominal.ine.mx/ESTADISTICAS/index.php), pero la pagina se va cargando conforme voy seleccionando los estados y el tipo de información.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Las páginas dinámicas requieren algo como Rselenium, investigalo, pero lamentablemente es un tema amplio y complejo para responder por aquí.

Comment: nodejs también provee herramientas de raspado para páginas dinámicas. Como (puppeteer)[https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer]

Comment: Ok, gracias, lo intentare